# Error: GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm trying to call an API URL but I will hit the error when my code run this line: `HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(uri)).Result;`,

This is the code.

```cs
public static string SimpleGetAsync(string uri)
{
     string result = string.Empty;
     try
     {
          HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
          {
              AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
          };

          HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);  
          HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(new Uri(uri)).Result;
                result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
                LogManager.WriteLogByDate(LogFile.Exception.ToString(), "Error HtmlHelper.SimpleGet (" + uri + ") :" + ex.Message + "\r\nWith stacktrace: " + ex.StackTrace + "\r\n\r\n");
     }
     return result;
}
```

This is the error message:

> One or more errors occurred. at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)

Comment: Well first try `.GetAwaiter().Result;` instead of `.Result;` https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/12/a-tour-of-task-part-6-results.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the method `async`

```
 public static async Task<string> SimpleGet(string uri)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(uri)).ConfigureAwait(false);
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogManager.WriteLogByDate(LogFile.Exception.ToString(), "Error HtmlHelper.SimpleGet (" + uri + ") :" + ex.Message + "\r\nWith stacktrace: " + ex.StackTrace + "\r\n\r\n");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

About [`ConfigureAwait`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

Comment: Hi @jjchiw, thanks for you comment but I still hit the error. And the error message is `TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()`.

Comment: and I call the method is like this way: `string pageSource = HtmlHelper.SimpleGetAsync(API_URL).Result;`

Comment: The issue is that you should use `async/await` instead of `.Result`... What happens is about SyncContext, Threading and how c# handle the `async/await` https://markheath.net/post/async-antipatterns section 4th (Blocking on tasks with .Result or .Wait)

Comment: @ jjchiw So did you means I have to use `async/await` to call the async task method?

Comment: I get: SimpleGetAsync dosn't exist ...